# Styling child components dynamically in react

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

***I am using sass to style my components by importing the compiled css per component, this will not dynamically style or scale well***

Context:

I have a main style-sheet for the main app component containing responsive UI classes with media queries and different custom column sizing's. I do not want to repeat these classes per child component of the main component... just to ensure each has access to them... **Am I approaching component styling in react the wrong way?**

**How else would I have my child components inherit css classes? Do I have to pass them down as props?** I feel like there is a better way to approach this problem...

**How would I maintain global style state when dynamically changing it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me, as suggested by Basile, I am using the emotion css-in-js library where styles go into styled components. emotion comes with a themeing mechanism to dynamically style css, and maintain global styling.

css-in-js styled components

```
const MButton = styled.button`
  background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.primarycolor};//using theme
  border: 3px solid $color;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  -ms-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  -o-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
`;
export default class index extends Component { ... your component
```

For global styling and themeing I used emotions theme, themeprovider, and global components. I define my themes in a seperate file, import it, apply

```
const makeGlobalStyles = (theme) => css` any additional global styling not dependent on differing themes in theme`; 
//supply styles to global component which manages global theme style state
const GlobalStyles = withTheme(({ theme }) => (
  <Global styles={makeGlobalStyles(theme)} />
));
```

store theme as a state in apps main component...

```
this.state = {
      viewState: "DARK",
      theme: theme.DARK,//use a method to change these states to then change the theme styles used across the app
```

Then provide theme state realtime to all components who utilize it

```
render(){
const {viewState,theme} = this.state;
return(
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <GlobalStyles />
     any logic for your application, pass prop theme to components to dynamically style to the theme
     <SomeComponent theme={theme}/>
<ThemeProvider/>
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am using sass to style my components by importing the compiled css
>   per component

**I would not recommend this approach.**
React is compiled with Webpack. If you use the create-react-app to initialize your new project you can just import any *.scss* file into your *index.js* and Webpack will compile it to a *.css* file and inject it into your HTML on build. If you do it this way you can use any *css* class anywhere in your React app.

More information here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-sass-in-create-react-app-v2

And here:  https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet

P.s.: I suggest you create an *scss* folder in *src* with one main *scss* file (e.g. app.scss). In *app.scss* you *@import* all your other *scss* files that can inherit variables and so on. Then import the *app.scss* into your *index.js*

Comment: The next problem I have, is I need to dynamically change the css values, such as the color theme. Which I believe means I have to do the styling manually in some instances through passing props... which sounds messy

Comment: Then you should use a CSS-in-JS library. In my opinion the best is [emotion.js](https://emotion.sh/docs/theming). There are others like [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/). You can find a complete list with comparison here: [https://github.com/tuchk4/awesome-css-in-js](https://github.com/tuchk4/awesome-css-in-js)

Comment: Could I use a mix? Or should I completely refactor my sass to fit in CSS-in-JS libraries?

Comment: Mixin both shoud not be a problem. You can for example style all the layout and grid system in the scss files then create custom buttons in CSS-in-JS that change color depending the theme.

Comment: Another solution (entirely in scss) would be to add a class on your body depending on the theme and create a different version of each component depending on that class. [This is a good post to understand the concept](https://medium.com/@dmitriy.borodiy/easy-color-theming-with-scss-bc38fd5734d1)

Comment: I switched over to react-bootstrap for the layout. The problem with the sass approach is I don't think I can change style real-time, as scss is a superset of css meaning it should be compiled. So unless i'm serving it server-side, changing the theme wont be possible real-time